# How do you scrape a website using scrapy which doesn't generate an api in the networks tab?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have scraped a lot of websites earlier, but I just am not able to understand how do I scrape [this](https://www.kap.org.tr/en/bildirim-sorgu) website using scrapy.
I basically have an input file which consists of company names, their stock codes,domicile name, etc.
The issue is such that neither there a json api getting generated in the Networks tab after inspecting or even if there is doesn't display the selected parameters, neither the url changes after selecting some fields.
I wanted to scrape the company names, publication date, the pdf file link and the year of each company.

Does anyone know a definite way of scraping such a website using scrapy?

Comment: The website is loading using javascript. You'll need to use one of the methods discussed [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html) to scrape it with scrapy

Comment: @tomjn: Thanks alot your help! will check this out